# System.IO File Created Date Behavior Issue

Tags: vb.net, windows-10, system.io.file

I wrote a windows service that compares large uncompressed images to their much smaller thumbnails to determine which images need new thumbnails or don't have thumbnails at all... I am using the Created Date of the files to determine which ones require updating (if an uncompressed image has a created date larger than the thumbnail then the thumbnail is out of date).

Everything is working great, my only issue is when I save new versions of the thumbnails over their existing ones... At first I was only doing a simple `Bitmap.Save` but when overwriting this would only change the Modified Date of the file. I added in a `File.Delete()` prior to saving the new version and it deletes the old version, saves a new one (as it should), but the Created Date of the new file is STILL THE OLD CREATED DATE...

I deleted every old thumbnail, waited a few minutes and then ran the creation code again, brand new create dates... Is there some timeframe Windows stores the file data in memory and perhaps its recognizing identical file names and giving the new files the old Created Date???

Comment: How can we possibly know without you showing us your code?

Comment: @rory.ap As I've explained there is no code to show, this is a Windows 10 behavioral issue. I was wondering if someone knew why Windows behaves like this... I am successfully deleting, successfully saving. No need to show code I explained im using `System.IO.File.Delete()` and `System.Drawing.Bitmap.Save()` .

Comment: There's always a need to show code.  I'm certain the issue is with your code, yet we can't know that without seeing it.  Either way, there's really nothing else we can do to help you because we don't have your computer in front of us.  How are we supposed to know what's going wrong?  As it stands, this question will probably be closed as off-topic because "why is my code not working" is off topic without more specific info and actually sharing your code.  Please read [ask].

Comment: Sure thing, I'll give it a go. As you probably well know Windows has weird constraints for their dates and how they assign them, that is what I was asking and it is shown in the post and the title. I specified the way I am deleting and saving and apparently that's not enough when I tell you I can see all the code working. This site has become a grab at whoever can comment "Show us ur code, tell us your DBMS, how can we possibly know what you're asking without sample data, etc.." and hoping to be the first to get the upvotes. Sad, I'll look elsewhere for what should be a simple explanation.

Comment: If you don't know how `System.IO.Bitmap.Save` handles create dates on new files when they are creating a new version of a file that was just deleted using `System.IO.File.Delete` then you don't need to comment just to harass me for the sake of a few upvotes on your comment, my code which will do nothing for this. @rory.ap Move along and help people you can actually help. My assumption is deleting and saving a file with the exact same name so quickly may not give windows enough time to realize its a new file and not an overwrite. That would be a simple answer to give..

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for the [File.SetCreationTime(String, DateTime) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setcreationtime?view=netframework-4.8),

> NTFS-formatted drives may cache file meta-info, such as file creation time, for a short period of time. As a result, it may be necessary to explicitly set the creation time of a file if you are overwriting or replacing an existing file.

However, if you want to be cautious, rename the original file, say by putting ".old" at the end. That way, it would have to create a new directory entry for the new file. Then, if something goes horribly wrong, there is still the .old copy of it (until you delete that).

Comment: Thank you very much, I figured as much, wasn't aware of a `SetCreationTime` method but that sounds like a definite alternative. For now I have decided to just allow overwriting and look at the thumbnail's Modify Date since that seems to be getting updated consistently or at least enough that I can trust it most of the time.